# ggstance(), dwplot() errors

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having problems with ggstance, I keep having the following errors:

```
> library(dotwhisker)
Loading required package: ggplot2
RStudio Community is a great place to get help:
https://community.rstudio.com/c/tidyverse
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘dotwhisker’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘ggstance’
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘dotwhisker’ was built under R version 3.6.3 
2: package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.6.3 
> library(broom)
Warning message:
package ‘broom’ was built under R version 3.6.3 
> library(dplyr)

Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

Warning message:
package ‘dplyr’ was built under R version 3.6.3 
> 
> # run a regression compatible with tidy
> m1 <- lm(mpg ~ wt + cyl + disp + gear, data = mtcars)
> # draw a dot-and-whisker plot
> dwplot(m1)
Error in dwplot(m1) : could not find function "dwplot"
```

I have tried using GitHub but this is also ending with the same error.

Comment: try reinstalling the package, `install.packages('dotwhisker')`

Comment: I have tried this a ggstance is still having problems installing.